# Doctrine: Dynamic schema attribute

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an Oracle database layout with a master account (i.e. MASTER), and a lot of other schemas, which contain the same objects (tables, views etc. with the same name) and some of these objects are granted to the master schema.

The only way to access these (sub-)schema-objects is to connect to the MASTER account and build dynamic SQL statements:

```
CONNECT master@db
SELECT x, y, z FROM SUB1.MYTABLE;
```

or

```
CONNECT master@db
SELECT x, y, z FROM SUB5.MYTABLE;
```

Now I try to access this layout with Doctrine. I can define the entities with a schema name.

```
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="MYTABLE", schema="SUB5")
 */
class MyTable {
}
```

But this not what I want. How I can set the schema attribute dynamically just before I execute a query to access SUB1 or SUB2 or SUB5 schema (depends on a given method parameter)?

```
$dql = array();
$dql[] = "SELECT m";
$dql[] = "FROM entities\\MyTable m";
$dql[] = "WHERE m.col1 = :foo";
$dql[] = "ORDER BY m.col2 ASC";

$query = $this->getEM()->createQuery(implode(" ", $dql));
$query->setParameter("foo", $bar);
$query->setMaxResults($limit);
$query->setFirstResult($offset);

$res = $query->getResult();
```

With DQL I can only reference the PHP object name (entity), but I would like to know, how I can add the schema name here.

Comment: Doctrine is pretty much a one table per entity and has no built in support for this sort of functionality.  If there is only three schemas than you could consider making three duplicate entities, one per schema each extending a common class.  Awkward but might work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lot of these sub-schemas. At the moment about 70. So it is not an option to duplicate entities.

Comment: Possibly I could use NativeQuery class, but I must disable Query/Result cache because the Id values will overlap between the sub-schema table records.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Doctrine code, which generates the table name. It comes from the `QuoteStrategy` instance within the configuration of the `EntityManager`. So I have created my own `QuoteStrategy` subclass first:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultQuoteStrategy;

class TrialQuoteStrategy extends DefaultQuoteStrategy {

    private $schema;

    public function replaceSchema(string $classSchema, string $schema): void {

        $this->schema[$classSchema] = $schema;
    }

    private function getSchema(?string $classSchema) {

        return $this->schema[$classSchema] ?? "";
    }

    public function getTableName(ClassMetadata $class, AbstractPlatform $platform) {

        $tableName = $class->table['name'];

        if (!empty($class->table['schema'])) {
            $tableName = $this->getSchema($class->table['schema']) . '.' . $class->table['name'];

            if (!$platform->supportsSchemas() && $platform->canEmulateSchemas()) {
                $tableName = $this->getSchema($class->table['schema']) . '__' . $class->table['name'];
            }
        }

        return isset($class->table['quoted']) ? $platform->quoteIdentifier($tableName) : $tableName;
    }

    public function getJoinTableName(array $association, ClassMetadata $class, AbstractPlatform $platform) {

        $schema = '';

        if (isset($association['joinTable']['schema'])) {
            $schema = $this->getSchema($association['joinTable']['schema']);
            $schema .= !$platform->supportsSchemas() && $platform->canEmulateSchemas() ? '__' : '.';
        }

        $tableName = $association['joinTable']['name'];

        if (isset($association['joinTable']['quoted'])) {
            $tableName = $platform->quoteIdentifier($tableName);
        }

        return $schema . $tableName;
    }
}
```

The class will be used during the `SqlWalker` AST to SQL creation. There is a new public method `replaceSchema`, which allows you to replace the entity class schema name with a given parameter. Within the entity class I define a dummy schema name:

```
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="MYTABLE", schema="dummy")
 */
class MyTable {

}
```

Before I use the `EntityManager` to build a new query I have to set the current schema for the dummy schema:

```
$this->getEM()->getConfiguration()->getQuoteStrategy()->replaceSchema("dummy", "my_current_subschema");
$query =  $this->getEM()->createQuery(implode(" ", $dql));
```

If you call `$query->getSQL()` you will see the modifications just before each table name. That's an ugly hack...

Comment: This works only for SELECT statements, there are a lot of other problems for SequenceGenerators and creating or removing entities within sub-schemas.